# Simple angular JS app not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I know there have been a million of these questions, but I sifted through a lot of them and can't seem to find any problems with my code.

```js
var app1 = angular.module('app1', []);
    
    app1.controller('ctrl1', function($scope){
    
        $scope.lines_list = 'waiting....';
        $scope.one = 1;
    
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="app1" ng-init="">
        <head>
            <title>Front End</title>
            <script src="index.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        </head>
    
        <body>
    
            <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
    
                <h1>Lines!</h1>
                {{lines_list}}{{one}}
                <input type="text" ng-model="lines_list">
    
            </div>
    
            
        </body>
    
    
    </html>
```

I've tried nearly everything so if anyone can tell me what's wrong here, please let me know.

Comment: What is your problem? What are you seeing and what do you expect to see?

Comment: Can you at least explain what the problem is? "Its not working" doesn't really tell us anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you are importing app.js, and after you import angular.js in index.html. Before you edited, I believe I saw your app.js imported before angular. -> `<script src="../app.js"></script>` **before** angular.min.js.
2. Remove [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit), what is it doing? -> `<html ng-app="app1">`

Comment: Thank you so much! it was the first option. I will accept your answer as soon as I can.